My website suddenly won't play any videos
My WordPress website - megaomega.org is suddenly not playing any video content. The website was designed such that it relies heavily on video content for the homepage layout and inner pages. If I go to change/update the videos that are embedded in the page layout, I see the error message displayed in the preview window. The message displayed is
"Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found
Download File: https://megaomega.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/megaomega-homepg-1442_converted-resized.mp4?_=0"
I am using the latest (paid) version of Divi to design the pages, and we have the latest version of WordPress running on PHP 7.4.33. The plugins are default.
I have tried everything, like using .mov and .mp4 formats interchangeably, resetting all site file/directory permissions, but nothing seems to help.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I checked your website and noticed that the URL for the video on the homepage is http://localhost:8888/megaomega/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/1066502404-sd.mp4 instead of https://megaomega.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/megaomega-homepg-1442_converted-resized.mp4. This appears to be the same across videos elsewhere on your site. Is the HTML for the video hard-coded into the Wordpress theme?

As @The-Coder-Who-Knew-Too-Little points out in his comment on the question, the video URLs are referencing a localhost domain. It's not just the videos, though - the logo and font URLs are affected too. It looks like some URLs weren't updated correctly in the process of moving from the local testing environment to the live environment.
To address this, first check that the WordPress and Site Addresses have been updated in "WP Admin > Settings > General".
Then correct the URLs on the logo and in the video modules by either re-uploading the content, or using a database search and replace plugin to replace the old site root URL "http://localhost:8888/megaomega/" with the new one "https://megaomega.org/".
Finally, clear Divi's cache at "WP Admin > Divi > Theme Options > Builder > Advanced > Static CSS File Generation > Clear", which should clear out the references that Divi's cache is holding to the old URLs (e.g. the fonts).
